# Google Places API and Destination URL

Tags: google-maps, mapkit

Is there a way to get a place's website through the google places API? For example, if I find a Barnes and Noble, is there a way for Google Places to return barnesandnoble.com in part of the xml/json response?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [current Places API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceDetailsResults), the URL of the location is not one of the returnable values, so it cannot be retrieved using the API.

The `url` field returned is the URL of the Google Places page for the location, not the web site of the location itself.